# I need to password protect multiple pages with PHP and MYSQLi objectively

Tags: php, database, mysqli, password-protection

Although I'm a complete beginner, I do know how to connect to a database, add to database and select from databases (last one I am not so good at).

I need a simple solution that allows me to have someone log in with a password and username and then it stores a cookie in their browser.

I also realise that for safety reasons I need to encrypt it, possibly with md5 and salt.

I just need a way of putting all of these things together to actually solve my problem.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: what you are asking for is the entire authentication module.  hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good solution:

http://phpsense.com/php/php-login-script.html

Comment: wouldn't recommend something that old.

Comment: But its good for a new person, because it explains the process very well.

Comment: @Dagon when you say you wouldn't recommend it, is it because the methods used are wrong? Otherwise, thanks RubyDev it seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.